# MySql Monthly Duration Matrix

Tags: sql, matrix, duration

I'm trying to write a single query that'll show a monthly duration matrix of hours worked. I'm trying to achieve this.

[image]

I currently have this. 
[image]

The correct output should be 
[image]

My SQL is

```
`SELECT WEEK(start) as weekId,
                (
                    SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start)))
                    FROM tbl_time_clock
                    WHERE WEEKDAY(start)=0
                ) AS Monday,
                (
                    SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start)))
                    FROM tbl_time_clock
                    WHERE WEEKDAY(start)=1
                ) AS Tuesday,
                (
                    SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start)))
                    FROM tbl_time_clock
                    WHERE WEEKDAY(start)=2
                ) AS Wednesday,
                (
                    SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start)))
                    FROM tbl_time_clock
                    WHERE WEEKDAY(start)=3
                ) AS Thursday,
                (
                    SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start)))
                    FROM tbl_time_clock
                    WHERE WEEKDAY(start)=4
                ) AS Friday,
                (
                    SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start)))
                    FROM tbl_time_clock
                    WHERE WEEKDAY(start)=5
                ) AS Saturday,
                (
                    SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start)))
                    FROM tbl_time_clock
                    WHERE WEEKDAY(start)=6
                ) AS Sunday
            FROM tbl_time_clock
            WHERE MONTH(start) = {$monthId} AND user_id = {$userId}
            GROUP BY WEEK(start)`
```

Table looks like

```
╔═════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ user_id ║        start        ║        stop         ║
╠═════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║       1 ║ 2012-08-28 08:14:49 ║ 2012-08-28 10:14:49 ║
║       1 ║ 2012-08-25 10:00:32 ║ 2012-08-25 16:21:57 ║
╚═════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need subqueries for this.

It is common to just **group by two fields**, and have your programming language do the presentation (create the table):

```
SELECT 
    WEEK(start) as weekId,
    WEEKDAY(start) as weekDay,
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start))
FROM tbl_time_clock
WHERE MONTH(start) = {$monthId} AND user_id = {$userId}
GROUP BY WEEK(start), WEEKDAY(start)
```

If your SQL itself MUST really give a matrix (but why?), try this:

```
SELECT 
    WEEK(start) as weekId,
    SUM( if( WEEKDAY(start)=0,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start))),0) as Monday,
    SUM( if( WEEKDAY(start)=1,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start))),0) as Tuesday,
    SUM( if( WEEKDAY(start)=2,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start))),0) as Wednesday,
    SUM( if( WEEKDAY(start)=3,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start))),0) as Thursday,
    SUM( if( WEEKDAY(start)=4,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start))),0) as Friday,
    SUM( if( WEEKDAY(start)=5,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start))),0) as Saturday,
    SUM( if( WEEKDAY(start)=6,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start))),0) as Sunday,
FROM tbl_time_clock
WHERE MONTH(start) = {$monthId} AND user_id = {$userId}
GROUP BY WEEK(start)
```

Comment: Thanks! Decided to go with your 2nd solution. Just had to move an inner bracket to the outside - SUM( if( WEEKDAY(start)=0,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start)),0)) as Monday

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to constrain the week in each of your subqueries. In order to do this, add an alias to your inner tables so the values from the outer query can be referenced in the inner query. The Monday subquery would look like this:

```
(
     SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start)))
     FROM tbl_time_clock AS tbl_inner
     WHERE WEEKDAY(tbl_inner.start)=0
     AND WEEK(tbl_inner.start)=tbl_outer.week_start
) AS Monday
```

The outer table should be grouped before the constrained subqueries execute, otherwise there will be multiple results per week. So your outer FROM clause should look like this:

```
FROM (
    select WEEK(start) AS week_start FROM tbl_time_clock GROUP BY WEEK(start)
    WHERE MONTH(start) = {$monthId} AND user_id = {$userId}
) as tbl_outer
```

EDIT: Fixed. Also, I agree with Konerak on probably not needing a matrix and his SQL solution is better. Leaving this since it shows how to modify the given SQL to get the solution.